# the expression is roughly equivalent to " Cover your breast over the baby's mouth"

Tags: expressions, slang, idiom-requests

In my own language, the "Cover your breasts over the baby's mouth" is such a lovely and interesting idiom. It's derived from the thing that is: a baby cries very much and the mother is too busy with her business and she dont appease a baby, she just "cover her breasts over the baby's mouth", immediately the baby no longer cries.

In my country this expression implies such as this situation: the guy A prosecute B, unfortunately for A, B has so much powers as well as money, so B just simply  uses these things to overcome the trouble. In general, the "Cover your breast over the baby's mouth" is action of high-rank people suppress the feelings, opinions of low-rank people, and this action is usually illegal or inappropriate.

I want to translate this expression into English in such a naturally way. Please suggest me something for this.

Comment: I'd say "Treating the symptoms and not the cause".

Comment: Marie Antoinette, in trying to achieve the same result, said, "Let them eat cake!"

Answer (score 2):

We can speak of *[throwing money at a problem](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/throw+money+at)* till it goes away or of a *whitewash* or *[papering over the cracks](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/paper-over-the-cracks)* (like wallpaper over a rough or cracked wall) but I'm not sure this is exactly the meaning you want.

Answer (score 2):

**suppression of dissent**

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppression_of_dissent)

> Suppression of dissent occurs when an individual or group **which is more powerful than another** tries to directly or **indirectly censor, persecute or otherwise oppress the other party**, rather than engage with and constructively respond to or accommodate the other party's arguments or viewpoint. When dissent is perceived as a threat, action may be taken to prevent continuing dissent or penalize dissidents. Government or industry may often act in this way.
>
> A cover-up is an attempt, whether successful or not, to conceal evidence of wrongdoing, error, incompetence or other embarrassing information. In a passive cover-up, information is simply not provided; in an active cover-up, deception is used.

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/suppression)

> The action of suppressing something such as an activity or publication:
> *the heavy-handed suppression of political dissent*

---

**cover-up**

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover-up)

> The expression is usually applied to people in **positions of authority**, such as police, who **abuse their power to avoid or silence criticism or to deflect guilt of wrongdoing**. Those who initiate a cover-up (or their allies) may be responsible for a misdeed, a breach of trust or duty, or a crime.
>
> While the terms are often used interchangeably, cover-up involves withholding incriminatory evidence, while whitewash involves releasing misleading evidence.

---

see also: blacklisting, chilling effect, coercion, whitewash, defamation

Answer (score 0):

To **sweep something under the rug** refers to an attempt to hide something unseemly or embarrassing, or to avoid solving a problem in a forthright way, as in:

> "The scandal was swept under the rug because of the important people involved in it." [(via)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sweep+under+the+rug)

Or:

> "It's an issue that's easy for the leadership here to sweep under the rug unless folks out there at the grass roots are heard from," said Jim Turner, a Democrat from Crockett, in East Texas. [(via)](http://www.thefreelibrary.com/CROSS-COUNTRY+REFORM+CRUSADER+REACHES+TEXAS-a083616547)

More prosaically, in the case of a high-ranking official suppressing a scandal, you might say that they **hushed it up** (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hushed+up).